# Helpers with Precompiled Views

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, precompile, razorgenerator

I'm using [RazorGenerator](http://razorgenerator.codeplex.com/) to Pre-compile my views. I also want to use Global Razor helpers(defined in cshtml files in App_Code directory). However the compilation throws up with the following error

> The name 'KarbonHelper' does not exist in the current context

However the intellisense seems to detect the helper methods. I've incorporated Razor pre-compilation as per the following blog [Razor Precompilation](http://stacktoheap.com/blog/2013/01/19/precompiling-razor-views-in-asp-dot-net-mvc-3/)

Also I notice that the helper file KarbonHelper.cshtml is actually pre-compiled into a .cs file in the expected location

```
obj\CodeGen\App_Code\KoolHelper.cshtml.cs
```

Any ideas or suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `App_Code` code generator process (controlled by Microsoft's code) creates you a static method, whereas the RazorGenerator creates you an instance method.

I'm still looking for a fix to this that doesn't involve a horrible hack.

Answer (score 1):

First try to add this under namespaces section under `system.web.webPages.razor` section in `Web.config` file in Views folder (change `MyProjectBaseNamespace` with the name of your project's base namespace - this is usually equal to the project's name - or just take a look in the generated file `KoolHelper.cshtml.cs` which namespace was used).

```
    <add namespace="MyProjectBaseNamespace.App_Code" />
```

If there are still errors try adding this directive in the first line of the helper in `App_Code`:

```
@* Generator: MvcHelper GeneratePrettyNames : true *@
```

RazorGenerator will then generate a class inheriting `System.Web.WebPages.HelperPage` with static `@helper` methods and with the class name same as the file name.

more info about directives:
https://github.com/RazorGenerator/RazorGenerator#special-razor-directives